# how to make dataframe select query generic in pyspark

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-databricks

Description :
I have  a list of column names which I need.
I want to check if all these columns names are present  in dataframe.if some columns are present then use those columns and make a generic code like

Df1=df.select(df[column1],df(column2])

List=[column1,column2,column3,column4]
Want to check if columns in list is present and whatever the columns are present in dataframe use it in select query

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in an iterative fashion

```
select_list = ['col1','col2','col3']
df_columns = sparkDF.columns ### ['col1','col2','col5','col7']

final_select_list = []

for col in select_list:
    if col in df_columns:
       final_select_list += [col]

### final_select_list --> ['col1','col2']


sparkDF.select(*final_select_list).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer(s) work perfectly. But it can also be written in a one liner.

```
# predefined list of all required columns
reqd_cols = ['id', 'dt', 'name', 'phone']

data_sdf. \
    select(*[k for k in data_sdf.columns if k in reqd_cols])
```

The list comprehension within the `select()` checks if any column from `data_sdf` dataframe is present in the `reqd_cols` list and keeps only the ones that are overlapping.